# How to stop this moving div

Tags: javascript, animation, html

This is my Javascript function

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var foo = null; // object
    function doMove() {
      foo.style.left = parseInt(foo.style.left)+1+'px';
      setTimeout(doMove,0); // call doMove in 20msec
      document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = foo.style.left;
    if(foo.style.left=='100px'){
     alert(foo.style.left);
    }}
    function init() {
      foo = document.getElementById('foo'); // get the "foo" object
      foo.style.left = '0px'; // set its initial position to 0px
      doMove(); // start animating
    }
    window.onload = init;
    </script>
    <div id="foo" style="width:100px;background:#99ccff;position: relative;">I am moving box</div>
```

Comment: Figure out how it works. How does the box move in the first place?

Comment: `#foo { left: 0 !Important; }` Actually you should use (at least consider) CSS3 transitions..

Comment: I need it moving until end of screen and stop

Answer (score 1):

Check if you `<div>` has reached the end-point you require (e.g. 100px), if so do not call the `setTimeout()` function anymore:

```
function doMove() {
  foo.style.left = parseInt(foo.style.left)+1+'px';
  document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = foo.style.left;
  if(foo.style.left=='100px'){
    alert("Finished");
  } else {
    setTimeout(doMove,20); // call doMove in 20msec
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I've created [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xmHMc/8/) for you. Look at css:

```
#foo { left: 100px!Important; }​
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/YYCUy/) with a stop button:

On clicking stop, set a flag to indicate you want the animation to stop. Check this flag before triggering the next stage of animation.

JS:

```
var foo = null; // object
var bAnimate = true;
function doMove() {
  foo.style.left = parseInt(foo.style.left)+1+'px';
  if (bAnimate) {
      setTimeout(doMove,0); // call doMove in 20msec
  }
  document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = foo.style.left;
if(foo.style.left=='100px'){
 alert(foo.style.left);
}}
function init() {
  foo = document.getElementById('foo'); // get the "foo" object
  foo.style.left = '0px'; // set its initial position to 0px
  doMove(); // start animating
}
function stop() {
    bAnimate = false;
}
    window.onload = init;​
```

HTML:

```
<div id="foo" style="width:100px;background:#99ccff;position: relative;">I am moving box</div>
<input type="button" onclick="stop();" value="stop" />
```

​

Answer (score 1):

Umm... Will this work?

```
  function doMove() {
      foo.style.left = parseInt(foo.style.left)+1+'px';
      if (!stop) setTimeout(doMove, 0); // if stop is false then call doMove in 20msec
      document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = foo.style.left;
    if(foo.style.left=='100px'){
      alert(foo.style.left);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Check out my [working answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14019523/967315). This is the same concept.

Answer (score 1):

[There you go](http://codepen.io/joe/pen/GyClk), even though I discourage this way of simulating animations.

```
function getLeftPx() {
  console.log(left+"px");
  return left + "px";
}

function init() {
  window.left = 0;

  var foo = document.getElementById('foo'); // get the "foo" object
  foo.style.left = getLeftPx(); // set its initial position to 0px
  doMove(); // start animating
}
window.onload = init;

function doMove() {

  window.moveInterval = setInterval( function() {
    left++;
    foo.style.left = getLeftPx();
    foo.innerHTML = left;

    if( left == 100 ) {
      clearInterval( moveInterval );
    }
  }, 20 );
}
```